# Nothing is rendering when I implement routing but if I render in separate components it renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

When I try to route and use the components it does not render anything.

Whereas when I try to render all the components individually then it is getting rendered.
So the problem is not with the problem I feel.

This is the code for app.js

```
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Header from "./components/header";
import Contact from "./pages/contact/Contact";
import About from "./pages/about/About";
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
    
export default App;
```

This is the code for index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You've mixed up some imported components. You've imported the `BrowserRouter` as `Route`, and then imported the low-level `Router` which is missing some required props.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

## Solution

Import `BrowswerRouter` as `Router`, remove the extraneous import of `Router`, and import `Route`.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```